# I have problem with object of class QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt

In the window I construct object of class QDockWidget and object of class QAbstractTableModel. This  objects shows the same data from table in SQL in different ways. When I mark the row in the object QAbstractTableModel the corresponding data is shown in object QDockWidget. It works when I mark the row by mouse, but when I move across the table by arrow (from keyboard) then I have problems. When I move down by the arrow then it works ok, but if I move up the data shown in object of class QDockWidget is not the same which was shown in marked row in object QAbstractTableModel. That was data of previous row in object QAbstractTableModel. Why it works like that? I want - the data will be always the same when I move up or down, the data form marked row in object of class QAbstractTableModel will be shown in object QDockWidget.

```
class Adresat(QDockWidget):
def __init__(self, parent):
  super().__init__(parent)
  ...
  self.widok = QTableView() 
  etykieta1 = QLabel("Nazwa   ")
  etykieta1.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
  etykieta2 = QLabel("Adres ")
  etykieta2.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
  ....
  Nazwa1Edt = QLineEdit()
  Nazwa1Edt.setMaxLength(100)
  Nazwa1Edt.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
  Nazwa1Edt.setReadOnly(True)
  AdresEdt = QLineEdit()
  AdresEdt.setMaxLength(50)
  AdresEdt.setFont(QFont("Arial",12))
  AdresEdt.setReadOnly(True) 
  ....
  uklad1 = QHBoxLayout()
  uklad1.addWidget(etykieta1)
  uklad1.addWidget(Nazwa1Edt)
  uklad1.addSpacing(290)
  uklad2 = QHBoxLayout()
  uklad2.addWidget(etykieta2)
  uklad2.addWidget(AdresEdt)
  uklad2.addSpacing(350)
  .....
  ukladV = QGridLayout()
  ukladV.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
  ukladV.addLayout(uklad1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
  ukladV.addLayout(uklad2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
  .....
  uklad.addWidget(self.widok)
  ....
  uklad.addLayout(ukladV, 2, 0, 1, 1)
  ......
  pola = ['Nazwa', 'Adres',..]
  self.model = TabModel4(pola) 
  ....
  self.widok.setModel(self.model)
  font = QFont("Tahoma", 11)
  style = "::section {""background-color: lightsteelblue; }"
  self.widok.horizontalHeader().setStyleSheet(style)
  self.widok.horizontalHeader().setFont(font)
  self.widok.setFont(font)
  ...
  dokogo = []   
  for d in tabelka1:
   dokogo.append([d[0],d[1],...)
  self.model.aktualizuj(dokogo)
  self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
  self.widok.hideColumn(1)
  self.widok.resizeColumnsToContents()
  self.widok.setSortingEnabled(True)
  self.widok.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
  self.widok.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
  self.widok.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
  self.widget = QWidget()
  self.widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
  self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
  self.widget.layout().addLayout(uklad)
  self.setWidget(self.widget)
  ....
class TabModel4(QAbstractTableModel):
""" Tabelaryczny model danych """

def __init__(self, pola=[], dane=[], parent=None):
    super(TabModel4, self).__init__()
    self.pola = pola
    self.tabela = dane


def aktualizuj(self, dane):
    """ Przypisuje źródło danych do modelu """
    self.tabela = dane

def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    """ Zwraca ilość wierszy """
    return len(self.tabela)

def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
    """ Zwraca ilość kolumn """
    if self.tabela:
        return len(self.tabela[0])
    else:
        return 0
def data(self, index, rola=Qt.DisplayRole):
    """ Wyświetlanie danych """
    i = index.row()
    j = index.column()
    if rola==Qt.BackgroundColorRole:
      if i%2: bgColor=QColor('#F5F5BC')
      else: bgColor=QColor('#EEE8AA')        
      return QVariant(QColor(bgColor))
    if rola == Qt.DisplayRole:
     Nazwa1Edt.setText(self.tabela[i][0]+self.tabela[i][1])
     AdresEdt.setText(self.tabela[i][2])
    ...
     return '{0}'.format(self.tabela[i][j])
    else:
     return QVariant()

def setData(self, index, value, rola=Qt.DisplayRole):
    """ Zmiana danych """
    i = index.row()
    j = index.column()           
    if rola == Qt.DisplayRole:
     self.tabela[i][j] = value


def flags(self, index):
    """ Zwraca właściwości kolumn tabeli """
    flags = super(TabModel4, self).flags(index)
    j = index.column()
    if j!= 0 and j != 1 and j != 2 and j!=3 and j!=4 and j!=5:
        flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable

    return flags



def headerData(self, sekcja, kierunek, rola=Qt.DisplayRole):
    """ Zwraca nagłówki kolumn """
    if rola == Qt.DisplayRole and kierunek == Qt.Horizontal:
        return self.pola[sekcja]
    elif rola == Qt.DisplayRole and kierunek == Qt.Vertical:
        return sekcja + 1
    else:
        return QVariant()`
```

When I mark the row in the object QAbstractTableModel the corresponding data is shown in object QDockWidget. It works when I mark the row by mouse, but when I move across the table by arrow (from keyboard) then I have problems. When I move down by the arrow then it works ok, but if I move up the data shown in object of class QDockWidget is not the same which was shown in marked row in object QAbstractTableModel. That was data of previous row in object QAbstractTableModel. Why it works like that? I want - the data will be always the same when I move up or down, the data from marked row in object of class QAbstractTableModel will be shown in object QDockWidget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I customized class QTableView, which I used and defined function keyPressEvent in this class and that helped. I previously defined this function but in wron class, I placed her in QAbstractTableModel.